# How to bind the model value to @html.DropDownlist

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, html.dropdownlistfor

I'm working in **ASP.Net MVC3**. I need to Bind my model value in a `@Html.DropDownlist`. I have populated my model with the list of items.

How can I bind my model with MVC `DropDownList`?

Comment: please post some code and what show what have you tried

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.MyValue
   new SelectList(Model.MyList, "ValuePropertyName", "TextPropertyName"))
```

Basically, you need to look up SelectList and how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

You should be doing like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.YourItem, 
    new SelectList(Model.YourItem, "Value", "Text")
)
```

before doing this, you need to pass your model to your view `return View(model);`

Hope it helps

Comment: I tried Likke this   @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Projects.ToList(), new SelectList(Model.Projects))

Comment: ya i view model result and my cshtml page model does not match in runtime

Comment: Please post your view code,controllers action and appropriate Model class. So,that we can see what was wrong with them

Comment: Sorry, what is value in this context?